# How can I fit my pages next to a sidebar style navbar in Next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, navbar

I am currently trying to get a site going with a sidebar style navbar, building in Next/React.js on VSCode.

I have managed to route successfully (Next makes this job pretty straightforward) but when I route to next pages, the page itself actually appears **behind** the navbar (see pic attached).

What do I need to do to get the content to automatically position itself in the remainder of available page?

(the text is aligned/justified center, so aside the navbar should appear in the centre of remaining space...)

[centre offset image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0fDQ.png)

NavBar CSS

```
 .navBarContainer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 275px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.navBarContainer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.navBarItem {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.liHeading {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Contact Page CSS

```
 .mainBanner {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 150vh;
  margin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your css codes of navbar and content.

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw added above ^^

Comment: Since your navbar is position: fixed and has a fixed width, have you tried adding `margin-left: 275px` (navbar width) or `width: calc(100% - 275px)` to `.mainBanner` ?

Comment: tried both of these but neither work (calc(100%-275) isn't a valid property value...)... I have created a Layout.jsx file to 'wrap' all children (components, pages etc) with the Navbar, so I dont need to recode it. I think the problem lies here, because the js engine isn't sensing the Navbar on the same layer as the resultant content.

Comment: i temporarily fixed (hacky as hell)'ed it by adding a padding to the contact page banner of 275px. Of course, this wont apply to all elements within the contact page and so feels a bit hacky and temporary.